# AngularJS to remote node js(express js) REST api connection time out error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http, express

The issue should be pretty clear in the title line. I have a node js REST api server being called by a client AngularJS app.

**Ports**

The server side is running on port 3000: the code is nice and simple:

```
app.get('/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.sendStatus( string );
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log( 'Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port );
});
```

The client side is running on port 8080: the http call looks like this:

```
var serverURL = "http://localhost:3000";
$http({ 
    url: serverURL, 
    method:"GET",  
    dataType: 'json' 
}).then( function ( data ) {
    $scope.message = data.data;
}, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
});
```

**Real Issue**

When I run this locally it works just fine with the code above. However, when I try to put the server side code on a cloud server with the ip address x.x.x.x I cannot seem to connect. The changes I make to my code are the obvious ones.

Client Side:

```
var serverURL = "http://x.x.x.x:3000";
```

Server Side:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, 'x.x.x.x', function () { ... }
```

The error looks like what you would assume:

```
GET: http://x.x.x.x:3000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I have no idea what is going on. I don't think its a timeout window being too small issue because it fails after 20 seconds. I could guess that I may need permissions in the server side code to be called from random clients, but I'm shooting in the dark here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to GET into your API with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)? What about "res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..."?

Comment: Yes same situation. When its running the service on the cloud it times out, when I run in locally it works fine.

Comment: Server logs? Mandatory port? What is your cloud server hosting?

Comment: unclear on all of that but the server is on redhat

Comment: I have the same problem, when trying to acces from a non local machine, the server timoutes, i tried to host my client app (AngularJs) on tomcat but in vain, same problem, did you find a solution ? Thanks !